# Subtracting random number does not match average I should get

Tags: python, random, average

Suppose you organize a competition with 25 million participants. At each round, a random number from the people remaining is eliminated. How many rounds should we expect to get 5 participants or less ? Now 25M/2^22 is the closest number higher than 5 so 22 rounds on average. However, when verifying this in Python, I get that the distribution is more accumulated around 15-16 rather than 22-23. (I am not very familiar with Python so I know I should use dictionaries to count stuff etc.) Is there a mistake in my code ? Because theory cannot lie.

```
import random

lst=list()
for j in range(1,10000):
    i=0
    X=25000000
    while X > 5:
        i = i+1
        elim=(random.randint(0,X))
        X = X - elim
    lst.append(i)
    
for i in range(1,33):
    print( i, "appears", lst.count(i), "times")

print("22 appears", lst.count(22)*100/len(lst), "% of the time")
print("15 appears", lst.count(15)*100/len(lst), "% of the time")
```

Comment: Theory might not lie but it can certainly be misapplied.

Comment: your python code looks good to me. you can also plot a histogram of the results with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.hist(lst)`. maybe ask at the math stackexchange? https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jkr thanks ! I'll ask on MSE ! (Since Im a math guy, I didn't expect my code to be good and theory false, it's always the opposite haha)

Comment: No, you shouldn't expect  22 rounds. You're not halving, your participants are not in elimination type of game.

Answer (score 3):

Expect about 16.33 rounds.

Let e[X] be the expected number of rounds for starting with X participants.

```
X <= 5:
  e[X] = 0

X > 5:
  e[X] = 1 + (e[X]/(X+1) + ... + e[0]/(X+1))
  e[X]*(X+1) = (X+1) + (e[X] + ... + e[0])
  e[X]*X = (X+1) + (e[X-1] + ... + e[0]
  e[X] = 1 + 1/X + (e[X-1] + ... + e[0])/X
```

In Python:

```
total = 0
for X in range(6, 25_000_001):
    e = 1 + 1/X + total/X
    total += e
print(e)
```

Output:

```
16.32826873439911
```

Running your experiment three times, printing the average `sum(lst) / len(lst)`:

```
16.352835283528353
16.27162716271627
16.315431543154315
```

Comment: Yep, looks about right. Not a halving, 1-on-1 game like tennis or fencing.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected result.

It happens because of the way the probabilities combine. You're expecting to reduce the value by half on average for each iteration, but that isn't actually what happens.

Reducing the value by 10% in a single iteration has the same probability as reducing it by 90% in a single iteration. If the value is reduced by 10% seven times in a row, it will be reduced to about 48% of the original value. If it is reduced by 90% seven times in a row, the result is reduced to 0.00001% of the original value.

In other words, the linear distributions of probabilities for what to reduce `X` by means that the times the reduction is high will have a greater impact than the times the reduction is low.

In order to get an average number of iterations roughly equal to `log2(25000000)`, you need a logarithmic random distribution.

Edit: I should clarify that this will happen with any decent PRNG. Just for sanity, I converted it to rust (code below) and it behaves the same way.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut results = HashMap::new();

    (1..10000).for_each(|_| {
        let mut i = 0;
        let mut x = 2u32.pow(30);

        while x > 5 {
            i += 1;
            x -= rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=x);
        }

        *results.entry(i).or_insert(0) += 1;
    });

    let mut sorted_results: Vec<_> = results.into_iter().collect();
    sorted_results.sort_by_key(|(k, _)| *k);

    for (k, v) in sorted_results {
        println!("{} {}", k, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the 48% and the 0.00001%, but those are just two out of many cases. What's the average of all cases? If I understand you correctly, those two cases are supposed to illustrate the *"reduce the value by half on average for each iteration, but that isn't actually what happens"*, but I don't see that, as it's not talking about the average.

Comment: Suppose you start with 1000. Then the value is reduced by 90% on the first iteration and by 10% on the second. Now the value is 90. If the value is reduced by 50% twice in succession, it is 250. I'm not good enough at math to explain this in any kind of formal way, but the times the result is reduced a lot affects the outcome more than the times the result is reduced a little, which biases the result to be lower than you'd expect from "half each time".

Comment: Trying all percentages with `mean(p*q/1e4 for p in range(101) for q in range(101))` gives me [0.25](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3I9OK8nMViksSSzKLSzKTixUycwvyi0oUclMT87i4Cooy80o0QGyNAq1CfcNUE4W0_CKFAoXMPIWixLz0VA1DA0NNsFghqpimJsQCqD0w-wA), though...